# How to create webparts like this one

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I want to create a webpart programmatically like below to contain fixed links to some internal pages:

[image]

The two shown in red blocks. How to create these webparts and attach to the site programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can accept your links to just be in the Top box, then just insert them into the QuichLaunch navigation

If you need them to be below the second box then you have to create a new MasterPage and insert some control below the PlaceHolderLeftActions ContentPlaceHolder

BR

Per

Comment: Seems a good option...but how can I go for the second one...can u explain more a bit? Everything needs to be done programmatically....

Comment: You should not do it all in code. But start by creating some standard ASP.NET Control which can show the links you want. Then use SharePoint Designer (SPD) to open the MasterPage and insert the control below the ContentPlaceHolder mentioned above. Now test that it's working. When satisfied on you dev enviroment use SPD to save the modified MasterPage to the file system and include it in a feature as described by http://mindsharpblogs.com/pauls/archive/2007/06/18/1903.aspx and also add you dll with the web control to the same feature

Answer (score 0):

Create Linnks webpart(site actions-->site settings-->site libraries and list--> create new content-->Tracking tab-->links web part
Then add your page urls and description here. Then go bak to your page and edit page--> add this web part there

Comment: I want to do that programmatically... :)